# How can i get output as below jn spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I have data like below.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Day | D1 |
| 1 | A | Tim | 1am |
| 1 | A | Tim | 3am |

Need to create like this

| A | B | Day | Tim1 | Tim2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | D1 | 1am | 3am |

Can you help how to get in spark scala

Comment: That's a basic `pivot` use case: `df.groupBy("A", "B").pivot("C").agg(first("D"))`

Comment: Yes pivot works here but if I have different values for same time, I have to split them into two

Comment: Then check the duplicates first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the row numbers for the duplicates first and then do the pivot.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w1 = Window.partitionBy("A", "B", "C").orderBy("D")
val w2 = Window.partitionBy("A", "B", "C")

val df1 = df0.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(w1)).withColumn("max_num", max("row_num").over(w2))
df1.show(false)

//+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+
//|A  |B  |C  |D  |row_num|max_num|
//+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+
//|1  |A  |Tim|1am|1      |2      |
//|1  |A  |Tim|3am|2      |2      |
//|1  |A  |Day|D1 |1      |1      |
//+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+


val df2 = df1.withColumn("C", expr("if(max_num != 1, concat(C, row_num), C)"))
df2.show(false)

//+---+---+----+---+-------+-------+
//|A  |B  |C   |D  |row_num|max_num|
//+---+---+----+---+-------+-------+
//|1  |A  |Tim1|1am|1      |2      |
//|1  |A  |Tim2|3am|2      |2      |
//|1  |A  |Day |D1 |1      |1      |
//+---+---+----+---+-------+-------+


val df3 = df2.groupBy("A", "B").pivot("C").agg(first("D"))
df3.show(false)

//+---+---+---+----+----+
//|A  |B  |Day|Tim1|Tim2|
//+---+---+---+----+----+
//|1  |A  |D1 |1am |3am |
//+---+---+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. It's working but some times I may not get two values still I want create two columns with with him and tim2